# How to add to openLDAP user objectClass

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have to clone data between two openLDAP servers. I obtain LDIF from source but I have a problem with import. I have error like 

`root@dc:/etc/ldap/schema# ldapadd -Y external -H ldapi:/// -f /tmp/export.ldif 
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
adding new entry "cn=Tomasz Topolski,ou=Pracownicy,dc=tropico,dc=local"
ldap_add: Invalid syntax (21)
    additional info: objectClass: value #3 invalid per syntax`

After googling I saw that problem is with 4th objectClass (because it start counting from 0), so i check and 4th objectClass in my exported ldif is

`objectClass: user`

And main question is. How to add this objectClass to my LDAP ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for migrating all configs, can use slapcat with "-n 0" as parameter to export the all configs including schema. Then, can add the schema first and then data.

But, if only this particular objectclass "user" is needed, then can follow below steps

1. Create a file user.schema with contents same as the source OPENLDAP user objectclass definition.
2. Create conf file user.conf 
   include ~/user.schema
3. Create a directory and run below commands

   mkdir userdir

   slaptest -f user.conf -F userdir
4. The resulting file in userdir can be used to add to schema

   service slapd stop

   slapadd -l  -n 0

   service slapd start